# sinon mock not catching calls

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I am having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong.

I have a JS class as such:

```
export default class A {

  constructor(repository) {
    this._repository = repository;
  }

  async process(date) {
    // ...

    this._repository.writeToTable(entry);
  }
}
```

and I am attempting to write a test that mocks the repository using `sinon.mock`

This is what I have so far:

```
describe('A', () => {
  describe('#process(date)', () => {
    it('should work', async () => {

      const repository = { writeToTable: () => {} };
      const mock = sinon.mock(repository);

      const a = new A(repository);

      await a.process('2017-06-16');

      mock.expects('writeToTable').once();
      mock.verify();
    });
  });
});
```

but it always fails saying that

```
ExpectationError: Expected writeToTable([...]) once (never called)
```

I've checked (added a console.log) and it is calling the object I defined on the test.

Comment: I am not super familiar with the ES2015 async/await construct, but in ES5 you need to add an argument callback function to the test function that will be called after your test has finished. Is this implicit? Alternatively, I guess if putting `async` in front of a function implies returning a Promise, then this should work as Mocha support returning promises to the test function.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this locally and read the documentation on [sinonjs.org](http://sinonjs.org/) and you seem to be doing everything right.

I tried re-writing your example using a `spy` and ended up with something like this to get a passing test:

```
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";

import A from "./index.js";

describe("A", () => {
  describe("#process(date)", () => {
    it("should work", async () => {
      const repository = { writeToTable: sinon.spy() };

      const a = new A(repository);

      await a.process("2017-06-16");

      expect(repository.writeToTable.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kristjan. I've changed my test, but wanted to understand why it wasn't working even though it seems like everything is right :/

Comment: @RaquelGuimarães I tried this too. But for me, the actual function is getting called.